# How to change the custom header for posts page (Wordpress Childtheme)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a custom page template for my wordpress theme that uses a custom header-file:

```
get_header('custom');
```

Everything works as expected, but when I set a page to be the **Posts-Page** somehow the standard header-file gets loaded instead (my custom page template is activated).

I have also tried to override the **blog.php** from the parent and added the explicit call to my custom header-file, but it didn't have any effect.

What am I doing wrong? How does this work?

Comment: What's the file name of you custom header file?

Comment: "header-custom.php" - as I said it works, just not on the posts-page.

Comment: Oh I see. Can you please show me the code of `single.php`

Comment: I didn't override single.php in my child theme. The single.php from the parent says `set_header();` but even if I do override it with my own version it still doesn't work :|

Comment: got it! I had to override `home.php`. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should override `home.php`

A bit more information `home.php` is the template used for the blog homepage (the page with all blogposts). You can learn more about which templates are being used where in the template hierarchy documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to override `home.php`.